# How to change properties of CSS thing in HTML at usage?

Tags: html, css

Sorry if the question is not really relevant, I'm french and I don't know the right terms of what I am asking exacly :)

Here is the 'thing' (module?) I've created to create a circle.

```
  .fake-avatar {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
  }
```

But I want to outline this one without creating this :

```
.fake-avatar-outline {
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
  }
```

Here is where I use it :

```
.fake-avatar-outline.rounded.flex-center.b-success.m-auto.bg-pink
  .fake-avatar.rounded.flex-center.b-success.text-xl.m-auto.bg-pink-light.icon-star
```

so the goal is to have only fake-avatar and change manually the size. How is it possible? Should I do something like that :

```
.fake-avatar.rounded.flex-center.b-success.m-auto.bg-pink(width='72px')
  .fake-avatar.rounded.flex-center.b-success.text-xl.m-auto.bg-pink-light.icon-star
```

Thank you,

Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly you are looking for a border

```
.fake-avatar {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;

    /* Add this*/
    border: 2px solid #FFF; /* color can go here */
    /* If you wanted a circle */
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

EDIT: As stated in the comments, the poster was also looking for a way to change the width of the element without having to change the class in the css file.  I said he could use inline-styles.

```
<div class="fake-avatar" style="width: 72px"></div>
```

I also noted that setting styles this way is usually frowned upon as it makes css maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but no i'm looking to outline the circle with an other color not just add border. And here is for the circle but I need to know how to change the size manually for other things like that. Thank you :D

Comment: You can change the color of the border by entering in another color.  In this case its the 3rd parameter and is set as white.

Comment: As I said this is not only about the circle it is for a general purpose. Can I change manually the size when I use it in html?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your case here.  You can also change the size of the border by increasing the 1st paramater.  In the answer it is `2px` you can change this to any value you want.

Comment: I have width = 70px. When I call .fake-avatar in HTML I want to set manually width = 72px. Without getting back in the css file or creating another .fake-avatar.outline. Is that possible? Like doing .fake-avatar.width=72px.rounded......... something like that?

Comment: Somewhat confused here.  You could set an inline style like so `<div class="fake-avatar" style="width: 72px"></div>`. Setting styles like this is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @DavidLee's answer, here a snippet with running code for both options.

```css
.fake-avatar {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:blue;
}

.fake-avatar-outline {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fake-avatar"></div>

<div class="fake-avatar-outline"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah I undestood thank you for the code. But what I am saying is: Is it possible to do these 2 circles using only 1 .fake-avatar? Like changing width to 72 px when I call it in HTML?

Comment: You can change the style properties of these elements in response to an event, using javascript.